# How to send string to device through Broadcast services? (Android Native)

Tags: broadcast

To send password wifi to that device. It not same with ACTION_HEADSET_PLUG broadcast concept. tq

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is it you want to accomplish and what problems do you have?

Comment: device link : http://www.amazon.com/Orvibo-Socket-Control-Appliance-Anywhere/dp/B00KT50HK4

actually i want to pass the wifi password to this device through my app